# Creating a string with separators from a list of numbers using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, join, separator

I have a list of numbers:

> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

I would like to create a string as follows:

```
Contains([saleID],"1") OR
Contains([saleID],"2") OR
Contains([saleID],"3") OR
Contains([saleID],"4")
```

I tried the following code:

```
print('Contains([saleID],"'.join(str(x) for x in list1).join('" OR'))
```

But I get the following output:

```
"1Contains([saleID],"2Contains([saleID],"3Contains([saleID],"4 1Contains([saleID],"2Contains([saleID],"3Contains([saleID],"4O1Contains([saleID],"2Contains([saleID],"3Contains([saleID],"4R
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.join(lst)` joins the elements of `lst` using `x` as a separator. Knowing this, you want to use `x = ' OR\n'` because that's what is repeated. The elements of `lst` can contain the rest of each line, i.e. `'Contains([saleID],"{num}")'`

There are two parts to this operation:

1. Format the number into the string `'Contains([saleID],"{num}")'`, which gives a list containing four strings as shown below:

```
>>> lst = [f'Contains([saleID],"{num}")' for num in list1]
['Contains([saleID],"1")',
 'Contains([saleID],"2")',
 'Contains([saleID],"3")',
 'Contains([saleID],"4")']
```

And,

2. Join all the formatted strings in this list with `' OR\n'`

```
>>> result = ' OR\n'.join(lst)
'Contains([saleID],"1") OR\nContains([saleID],"2") OR\nContains([saleID],"3") OR\nContains([saleID],"4")'
```

Print `result` to see that we have the desired value:

```
Contains([saleID],"1") OR
Contains([saleID],"2") OR
Contains([saleID],"3") OR
Contains([saleID],"4")
```

---

Of course, you can do this all in a single line with:

```
>>> result = ' OR\n'.join(f'Contains([saleID],"{num}")' for num in list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = 'Contains([saleID],"'
print(c + ('") OR\n'+c).join([str(x) for x in list1]) + '")')
```